# Copy Excel table data to TinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, html, excel, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinyMCE editor to allow users to create content for their articles. Also it allows users to copy and paste excel and word content to the editor.

When I copy excel table into the editor, Header row is treated as a `div` element. As I noticed header rows `td` has `<b>`. When I remove `<b>` tag header row also works as expected. Sample content is as follows:

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <b> <td></td></b>
    <b> <td></td></b>
    <b> <td></td></b>
    <b> <td></td></b>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>
     <td></td>           
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Sample Table that i'm coping from excel

[image: Table that i'm coping from excel]

Output in editor

[image]

Editor configuration as follows:

```
paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
paste_strip_class_attributes: "none",
extended_valid_elements: "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],table[style|class|border=2|width|cellspacing|cellpadding|bgcolor],colgroup,col[style|width],tbody,tr[style|class],td[style|class|colspan|rowspan|width|height],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]",
```

Any idea to get this header row to the editor or any proper way to extract `<table>` tag and remove `<b>` tags from the content?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is meant by "extract `<table>` tag", but to remove `<b>` you could configure paste_preprocess option for paste plugin.
Something like this should do the job:

```
paste_preprocess: function(plugin, args) {
 console.log(args.content); // your content
 args.content = args.content.replace(/<b>\s*<td>([^td]+)<\/td>\s*<\/b>/gmi, "<td>$1</td>");
}
```

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_preprocess